# Remove one duplicate digit from group of duplicate digit from integer to get maximum

Tags: algorithm

I had faced on question in my exams .Given a number with group of duplicate digits ,how would you remove one duplicate digit to get maximum.
Eg:112233 remove any one digit ie:either remove one 1 or one 2 or one 3 and return maximum number.How can this be done efficiently .One is brute force.

Comment: Does the duplicate digits always come together? That means could you have a number like 321123?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Remove one duplicate digit from group of duplicate digit from integer to get maximum

To ensure the maximum, we remove the smallest duplicated digit from the left. We don't have to perform brute force.

**Test on 112233:**

```
12233    //remove 1 (remove smallest from left) [formed largest]
11233    //remove 2
11223    //remove 3
```

**Test on 332211:**

```
33221    //remove 1 (remove smallest from left) [formed largest]
33211    //remove 2
32211    //remove 3
```

**Test on 221133:**

```
22133   //remove 1 (remove smallest from left) [formed largest]
21133   //remove 2
22113   //remove 3
```

Comment: What if the number is 12553664? 
Removing 5 will result in 1253664 which is less than 1255364 (got by removing 6)

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the first duplicate digit which is followed by a larger digit. This way you increase the most significant digit you can increase, resulting in the maximum.

Comment: You are right. But if we don't find such a digit, then we should traverse from right to left to find the first duplicate digit which is followed by a smaller digit.

Answer (score -1):

1. Traverse from left to right. Find the first duplicate digit that is followed by a larger digit. If you can find one, remove it and return the number (Eg: 122334)
2. Traverse from right to left. Find the first duplicate digit that is followed by a smaller digit. If you can find one, remove it and return the number. For example, In 455233, as we are traversing from right to left, '2' is a smaller digit that is followed by duplicate digits '3'.
3. Find the last duplicate digit, remove it and return the number (Eg: 433221)
4. If no duplicate digits, return the number

Few examples:

122334 - Falls under step 1. Remove 2 to get the largest number (12334)

455233 - Falls under step 2. Remove 2 to get the largest number (45533)

12553664 - Falls under step 2. Remove 6 to get the largest number (1255364)

433221 - Falls under step 3. Remove 2 to get the largest number (43321)

332211 - Falls under step 3. Remove 1 to get the largest number (33221)

Comment: `Traverse from right to left. Find the first duplicate digit that is followed by a smaller digit. If you can find one, remove it and return the number` A test case of `332211` will give you `32211` instead of a correct output of `33221`

Comment: @user3437460 I guess you misunderstood my logic. Remember that you are traversing from right to left. So in case of 332211, you won't find a duplicate number that is followed by a smaller digit (traversing from right to left and not from left to right). This will fall under step 3.